# A question about strongly compact cardinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals

Is the following equiconsistent with the existence of a strongly compact cardinals:

> For every $\lambda > \kappa$ there exists a $\lambda$-strongly compact embedding $j: V \to M$ with the additional property that $V$ and $M$ agree about the cardinals up to $\lambda.$

If yes, are there any references for this?

Comment: Do you know whether the property can fail in a model in which $\kappa$ is strongly compact? For example, does it fail when you force to make the least measurable cardinal strongly compact? Obviously, supercompact is an upper bound for the consistency, since supercompact cardinals have this property. So the consistency strength is between strongly compact and supercompact, which many people have conjectured are equiconsistent.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I have no idea about what can happen when we just start with a strongly compact cardinal.